# Get subfolders csv files with names starting with string

Tags: csv, pyspark, wildcard

I have the following tree structure in my databricks project:

```
/root
     Year1
       |_ Week 1
            |_ a_1312.csv
            |_ a_1312.csv
            |_ b_1312.csv
            |_ c_1312.csv
       |_ Week 2
       |_ Week 3
       |_ ...
     Year2
       |_ ...
```

I am trying to get all the `csv` files that start with `a_`. I am trying to use `recursiveFileLookup` with a wildcard but it is not working.

```
spark.read \
      .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
      .option('inferSchema', True)\
      .option('header', True) \
      .option('delimiter', ',') \
      .csv(mount_point  + "[a_*].csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/xxxx/**/[a_*].csv
```

It looks like the wildcard is not working and it is being processed as part of the string

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be something like this

```py
/root/*/*/a_*.csv
      ^ ^
   Year Month
```